# Unit Testing for the Controllor SpringBoot Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

Need to do Unit Testing for the Controller part of the project but have got the error. Believe ModelAndVIew part cause the issue, even though I have mocked it and returned ModelAndView as it is return type of method. However, it does not work. Do not have any issue with Pom.xml, therefore, did not add it. 
    ProjectController:

```
package com.bsptech.itcommunity.controller;

import com.bsptech.itcommunity.entity.Itproject;
import com.bsptech.itcommunity.service.inter.EmployeeProfileServiceInter;
import com.bsptech.itcommunity.service.inter.ItProjectServiceInter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/projects")
public class ProjectController {

    @Autowired
    private ItProjectServiceInter itProjectServiceInter;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeProfileServiceInter employeeProfileServiceInter;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/{projectId}")
    public ModelAndView detail(@PathVariable("projectId") Integer projectId, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        Itproject itproject = itProjectServiceInter.findById(projectId);
       modelAndView.addObject("itproject", itproject);
        modelAndView.setViewName("project/details");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView index(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        List<Itproject> projectList = itProjectServiceInter.findAll();
        modelAndView.addObject("projectList", projectList);
        modelAndView.setViewName("project/index");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/join", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String joinTeam(@RequestParam("projectId") Integer projectId){

        int result= employeeProfileServiceInter.joinProject(projectId);
        if(result==2)
            return "redirect:/projects/"+projectId+"?alreadyjoined";
        else if(result==1)
            return "redirect:/projects/"+projectId+"?joinsuccess";
        else if(result==3)
            return "redirect:/projects/"+projectId+"?alreadysent";
        else
            return "redirect:/projects?error";
    }
}
```

ProjectControllerTest

```
@WebMvcTest(ProjectController.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ProjectControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ItProjectServiceInter itProjectServiceInter;

    @MockBean
    private EmployeeProfileServiceInter employeeProfileServiceInter;

    @Mock
    ModelAndView modelAndView;

    @Test
    public void detail() throws Exception {
      OngoingStubbing resultItProject =  when(itProjectServiceInter.findById(1)).thenReturn(new Itproject(1));
        when(modelAndView.addObject(resultItProject)).thenReturn(new ModelAndView("project/details"));
        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/{projectId}").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        MvcResult result = mockMvc
                .perform(request)
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().json("project/details"))
                .andReturn();
    }


}
```

> ```
> Error Which I have found it: 
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.bsp.tech.it.community.controller.ProjectControllerTest.detail(ProjectControllerTest.java:44)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>   at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>   at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
>   at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
>   at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
> ```

When I am using

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ProjectController.class)
public class ProjectControllerTest {
```

**Getting an initialization error:**

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a
>   @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or
>   @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
>
> at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)    at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.getOrFindConfigurationClasses(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:233)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.processMergedContextConfiguration(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:149)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper.processMergedContextConfiguration(WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper.java:36)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:395)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:265)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:98)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.(TestContextManager.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.(TestContextManager.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.(SpringRunner.java:49)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
>     at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
>     at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)

**And In the pom.xml Using this dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If you want to test a controller then `@WebMvcTest` is what you need, don't combine it with `@SpringBootTest` as that is intended for full integration tests. You use one or the other, not both. The second error probably indicates that the package of your test is not correct as no class annotated with `@SpringBootAnnotation` can be found by the test code. In which package is your test class?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use both `@WebMvcTest` and `@SpringBootTest`.

Try:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ProjectController.class)
public class ProjectControllerTest {
...
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, Once I use with you comment, have got the initialization error. :

Comment: Are you using junit5 or junit4? What kind of initialization error? Please update the answer with a stacktrace...

Comment: I am using Spring Boot Starter Test, did not use any specific Junit4 or 5